# How to update a widget after pressing the button in a different widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to figure out how to make a widget that could trigger an update in a different widget. In this example changing the month/year in Month_Display widget has to update set of labels in Input_Table widget. Days with the red background represent weekends.

I have no idea how to get down to it. How can I call the make_month() function outside the class or how can I trigger Month_Display widget to reload the month?

Here is my example code:

```
from tkinter import *
import calendar
import datetime

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        # Widget
        self.input_table = Input_Table(self, self, borderwidth = 3, relief = RIDGE)       
        self.month = Month_Display(self, self, borderwidth = 3, relief = RIDGE)

        # Frame positioning 
        self.input_table.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.month.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky = NE)

    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()



class Input_Table(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.labels = {}
        self.world_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
        self.world_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
        self.world_day = datetime.datetime.now().day

        self.make_month()

    # Show dates on the left side of the table 
    # Piece of code that I want to trigger whenever button is pressed
    def make_month(self):
        date = datetime.datetime(year = self.world_year, month = self.world_month, day=self.world_day)
        the_day = datetime.datetime.weekday(date)
        for day in range(1, calendar.monthrange(self.world_year, self.world_month)[1] + 1):
            if (the_day) == 5 or (the_day) == 6:
                self.labels[day] = Label(self, text=day, bg="red")
            else:
                self.labels[day] = Label(self, text=day)
            self.labels[day].grid(row=day, column=0)
            date += datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
            the_day = datetime.datetime.weekday(date)


class Month_Display(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, the_date, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        self.selected_month = IntVar()
        self.selected_month.set(datetime.datetime.now().month)
        self.selected_year = IntVar()
        self.selected_year.set(datetime.datetime.now().year)

        # Widgets
        # These two buttons have to trigger the make_month()
        self.button_left = Button(self, text="<<", command=lambda: self.update_month(-1))
        self.button_left.grid(row=1, column = 0)

        self.button_right = Button(self, text=">>", command=lambda: self.update_month(1))
        self.button_right.grid(row=1, column = 4)

        self.month_label = Entry(self, textvariable=self.selected_month, width=3)
        self.month_label.grid(row=1, column = 1)

        self.slash = Label(self, text="/")
        self.slash.grid(row=1, column = 2)

        self.year_label = Entry(self, textvariable=self.selected_year, width=5)
        self.year_label.grid(row=1, column = 3)


    # Updating month and year
    def update_month(self, offstet):
        self.selected_month.set(self.selected_month.get() + offstet)
        if self.selected_month.get() > 12:
            self.selected_year.set(self.selected_year.get() + offstet)
            self.selected_month.set(1)
        elif self.selected_month.get() < 1:
            self.selected_year.set(self.selected_year.get() + offstet)
            self.selected_month.set(12)

app = App()
app.run()
```

Answering such question will give me an insight on how to make widgets communicate with eachother.

Comment: Are you saying that I have to call `Input_Table.__init__(...` every time the button is pressed?

Comment: In order to change the numbers displayed in the `Input_Table` class. My point is to change them when the button `button_right` or `button_left` in `Month_Display` is being pressed.

Comment: Got it! Do inside `Month_Display.update_month(...` `self.master.input_table.make_month()`. To got this working you have to correct the missing inheritance parameter `parent` to `Frame.__init__(self, parent,`. You are using **static** `datetime.now`, therefore you will **see no changes**!

Comment: It works! Much thanks! Assuming that I have multiple widget classes, is it possible to freely call other class functions like in this case?

Comment: *"possible to freely call other class functions"*: Yes, you only need the instance reference and the required parameters. BTW: `self.master` is the `class attribute` used by `tkinter`. If not passed, `root` are used by default. Did you realized that you have to `.destroy()` all `Label` before creating **new ones**?

Comment: _"Did you realized that you have to_ `.destroy()`"  Yup, I managed to do it by iterating over `Input_Table.labels` and `self.labels[l].destroy()`. Once again thank you so much.

Comment: Another mistake, you have to use `self` only once `Month_Display(self, borderwidth = 3, ...`